# Should i customize existing magento CSS or i should include bootstrap and use that instead

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, magento, custom-theme

I am planning to customize `magento design from scratch`, for that i have investigated and found many solutions, some with `bootstrap` and some without `bootstrap`. I just wanted to confirm what is the `best practice` for this, should i invest my time mixing bootstrap or should i just edit existing magento css file.

Comment: in both cases you have to edit the magneto existing css.

Comment: Okay, you mean in some parts i have to put `rwd` css compulsory. So in that case what is the best practice should i include bootstrap or not.?
I mean is it advisable to use bootstrap with magento, because we anyhow  have to use rwd css. Right?

Comment: if you want to add bootstrap start with default theme. not rwd.

Comment: you mean `base` theme.?

Comment: yes i mean theme because default is easy to customize as compare to rwd

Comment: Okay, i have just now applied and tested `default > default` and `defult > modern` and `default > blank` so `default > default` is best to start with right.??

Comment: `default > blank` is best to start.

Comment: Okay, thank your for your help and support. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add bootstrap file and start editing the magento styles.css. If not interested to edit style.css, then unlink that file from page.xml and stop using styles.css. Add your custom files and bootstrap to create the new outfit of your website.

Comment: Your talking about the default theme.?